# Como buscar várias colunas junto com o max() SQL (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, select, tabela-banco-de-dados

O problema é o seguinte, tenho as tabela `protocolo` e `historico`; segunda guarda vários registros vinculados a um registro da tabela de protocolos. Eu queria buscar o último registro de cada *histórico* por *protocolo*, porém junto com o restante dos campos da tabela de *histórico*, por exemplo

```
SELECT MAX(id_historico), id_local, id_situacao, id_protocolo 
FROM historico 
GROUP BY id_protocolo
```

O problema é que, quando faço essa consulta ele retorna o `id_histotico` máximo corretamente, porém o restante dos campos não é da mesma linha do `id_historico`, está voltando outros campos errados. Alguém poderia me ajudar a entender e resolver isso?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer uma *subconsulta* pra carregar primeiro os `id_historico` que serão exibidos; com isso, poderá carregar no *select* os dados (*id_local* e *id_situacao*) daquele item específico, restrigindo isso no `where`:

```
SELECT id_historico, id_local, id_situacao, id_protocolo
FROM historico
WHERE id_historicoIN (SELECT MAX(id_historico) FROM historico GROUP BY id_protocolo);
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, eu atualmente utilizo esse método que você citou mesmo, porém é ele é um pouco pesado e quanto mais dados na tabela mais pesado vai ficando. Eu estou buscando uma alternativa mais eficiente, pra não precisar comparar o id_historico com todos os dados da tabela através do IN ().

Comment: basicamente estou tentando evitar sub select

Answer (score 0):

Outra opição, se estiver usando `mysql` versão 8+, é usar o `ROW_NUMBER() OVER`, para gerar um número de "ordem" para cada historico, baseado no id_protocolo:

```
WITH UltimoHistorico AS (
  SELECT h.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id_protocolo ORDER BY id_historico DESC) AS id_ordem
  FROM historico AS h
)
SELECT * FROM UltimoHistorico WHERE id_ordem = 1;
```

Basicamente, gera uma sequência numérica, em ordem descedente, baseado no id_protocolo, ou seja, esse número quando for "1", é o último

Um exemplo funcionando pode ser visto aqui: [https://www.db-fiddle.com/](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qDy3FiK5Lsnkpwdi5zQdHA/0)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, estou procurando algo nesse caminho mesmo. Vou testar essa solução e se der certo para mim eu informo.